# Is there a way to determine what process started another one?

Tags: macos, mac, osx-lion, process

If I recall right you can determine some of the parameters a process was started with (in Windows it is stored in the Process Environment Block). Can I also find out what process started another one?

Example: My iTunes (memory eating "§$%&!) keeps reappearing even after I killed it and I wan't to know why. On the other hand I would find such knowledge useful in general and not only in this case ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can find out the parent process of another process by opening *Utilities » Activity Monitor.app*. Select the process, press *Inspect*.

[image]

Does't look too useful since almost everything in OS X is launched by `launchd`. I'm not sure there's anything better – I could be wrong though.

In the specific case of iTunes starting "by itself", it's probably due to a device being synced. Connect the iPad, iPhone, and uncheck "Open iTunes when this … is connected" in its settings.

Comment: Or, when you're happen to be on a terminal (or just a click away), `ps waxl` and `top` show the PPID too. `top` can help you with process list too.

Comment: Thank you! Both solutions work and the outcome is as predicted. I prefer the cli version ;-) iTunes is spawned because I have wireless-sync enabled.